# "Fake" OOP in C - how to deal with destructors and fake function epilogues on returning

Tags: c, oop

I am doing some experiments with faking OOP in C, and I've stumbled upon a conundrum. In C++ I assume the compiler inserts destructors in the function epilogue, after the `return` statement has been executed.

Faking that in C would require the destructors be manually invoked in the appropriate order, but the problem is the return value might depend on some of those objects, so at one hand destruction cannot occur before the return statement, on the other hand statements after the return statements are never reached. And the issue becomes more complicated by the fact there might be multiple return statements from inside different blocks which require their own respective fake epilogues.

So the question is how can I possibly deal with it? It doesn't have to be nice, since it doesn't look like it can be...

So far the best I could come up was to "cache" the return value at the moment of its return, do all the cleanup and after all that simply return the cached value, but I wonder if a a more efficient solution might exist, and on a side note on how well the compiler will deal with this one to minimize its eventual overhead. Sort of:

```
T foo() {
    T _retValue;
    ...
    if (something) {
        ...
        _retValue = someValue;
        goto blockID_cleanup;

        blockID_cleanup:
        ...
        goto foo_cleanup; // goto parent block until function block
    }

    _retValue = somethingElse;
    goto foo_cleanup;

    foo_cleanup:
    ...
    return _retValue;
}
```

Comment: Half of me wants to know *why* you'd go to all this trouble when Bjarne already did it for you three decades ago.

Comment: Its not possible to execute before the return, and that isn't what C++ does, the generated code just calls dtors before the return like any normal function

Comment: @JohnZwinck - why did you ever learn to go through the trouble of putting your pants on after your parents did that for you n decades ago? ;) As for me - my inquiring organ wants to know. Is that a bad thing?

Comment: @paulm - and if the destructors delete memory that the return statement actually needs to return from? Segfault? I don't think that's what happens.

Comment: @user: I think what John means is, doing all of this will teach you to little to nothing useful about OOP...

Comment: @user3735658 what do you mean? dtors do not return values

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - I want to know how OOP works, how to work with OOP is an entirely different subject. That is why I am trying to implement its paradigm in C, cuz C doesn't hide anything under the rug so to speak.

Comment: What is it that you think C++ is "hiding" from you? Dtors are called at end of scope, if args don't match and 1 arg ctors are not explicit then there can be implicit conversions, virtual calls incur a pointer lookup etc.. not really "hidden"

Comment: @paulm - I never said destructors return values. You said destructors are called before the return statement, but if a destructor deletes a member's data that the return statement actually needs to return then there will most likely be a fatal error.

Comment: I'll post an answer with some pesudo code showing what I mean, comment is too limiting

Comment: @paulm C++ generates tons of code for you. All that is effectively hidden complexity. Complexity I am interested in. Got it?

Comment: That makes sense. But I'd argue that a cleaner way to understand it is to implement a simple OO compiler, rather than trying to shoehorn the behaviour into C (as that approach has serious limitations).

Comment: C is portable. And readable. What you suggest is non-portable and not as readable (platform specific assembly I mean), so I doubt it will be simpler to do than do in C. It is not a matter of working in such a manner, which would be overly and unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: C++ uses copy on return concept. Return value is preallocated by the calling code (this how it would look like in C), then called code fills it in, and destroys internal objects.

Comment: @Basilevs - I commend you. That's what I expected, not people teaching me what I should care about instead or shoving stuff I already know in my face cuz they didn't get what I was asking. So my approach is what effectively C++ does? That's what I needed to know. Thanks a lot, should have posted that in an answer so I can accept it and so it can be easy to find for other users who might be wondering that in the future.

Comment: Your approach is not same - you allocate resources referenced in return value within your function. This does not happen in C++ - code that allocates resource should own it and dispose eventually.

Comment: @Basilevs - so what you mean is instead of using a `return` statement, the proper way to implement that would be to pass a `retAddress` parameter and instead of `return X` do a `*retAddress = X` provided storage is already preallocated by the callee? Would that be "as efficient" as relying on the return statement?

Comment: @user3735658, yes, without any optimizations it would exactly like that. Note, that most languages with stack work this way - a storage is allocated on stack and filled with data. When called function terminates, calling continues to own and manage data.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Seems you're actually asking how objects are returned from functions, your question isn't 100% clear but here goes:

```
class A
{
  public:
    A(int value)
     : mTest(value) {}

    A operator + (const A& other)
    {
      return mTest + other.mTest;
    }

    operator int()
    { 
      return mTest;
    }

  private:
    int mTest = 0;
};

int foo()
{
   A a(2);
   A aa(4);
   return a + aa;
}
```

This would become the following pesudo code:

```
int foo()
{
   A a;
   A aa;
   a_ctor(&a, 2);
   a_ctor(&aa, 4);

   A temp;
   a_copy(temp, a_operator_plus(a, aa)); // temp is another "instance"       

   // no need to worry about the dtors, the return value references nothing from these objects that isn't in scope anymore. If it did then this would be an error even in C++, so don't worry about that
   a_dtor(&aa);
   a_dtor(&a);

   return temp.mTest;
}
```

C++ "generated" code will not call dtors "after" the return statement. Dtors are called just like any other function.

Assume the C++ code is:

```
class A
{
public:
  A(const A&) = delete;
  A& operator = (const A&) = delete;
  A()
  {
     std::cout << "A ctor" << std::endl;
     mExampleBuffer = new char[128]; // allocate resources example, we don't do anything with this..
  }

  ~A()
  {
     std::cout << "A dtor" << std::endl;
     delete[] mExampleBuffer;
  }

private:
  char* mExampleBuffer = nullptr; // in real code this would be a std::vector or std::unique_ptr
};
```

Then used as:

```
void foo()
{
    A a;
    return; // not required, but here for clarity
}
```

Then in C this would be:

```
struct A
{
   // there is no "private" in C, so we need people to read this comment and not mess with  mExampleBuffer
   char* mExampleBuffer;
};

void a_ctor(A* thisPtr)
{
    printf("A ctor\n");
    thisPtr->mExampleBuffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*128);
    if (!thisPtr->mExampleBuffer)
    {
        // TODO: In C++ this would throw, in C you're gonna have to use setlongjmp or some such to simulate it.. plus use some sort of "cleanupstack" to do the unwinding
    }
}

void a_dtor(A* thisPtr)
{
    printf("A dtor\n");
    free(thisPtr->mExampleBuffer);
}

void foo()
{
    A a = {};
    a_ctor(&a);
    a_dtor(&a); // nothing magic here, simply called before the return statement
    return;    
}
```

As you can see for lots of classes using "real" C++ with RAII this would become a complete nightmare.. also you're not taking into account that the actual generated code would probably inline this so that there is no "class", i.e it would look something like:

```
void foo()
{
    printf("A ctor\n");
    char* mExampleBuffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*128); // not sure if would remove this or not since not used :) didn't check
    printf("A dtor\n");
    free(mExampleBuffer);
    return;    
}
```

Hopefully this explains the dtor mechanism. Don't forget that with inheritance each dtor must call the base.

Comment: In the comments you said, and I quote "the generated code just calls dtors before the return like any normal function", and now you say "C++ "generated" code will not call dtors "before" the return statement" which is effectively what I've been trying to explain to you. Maybe you mistake the `ret` procedure for the `return statement`? One returns to a previous point of execution, the other returns a value...

Comment: I've probably badly worded that, I mean you are implying they are called after when they are not, they are called like any normal function - edited :)

Comment: I didn't mean they are called after the `ret` but after the returned value has been "returned" to wherever it is needed, which is still before `ret`.

Comment: You mean if class A returned a value from a member function? I don't understand what you mean as C++ dtors do not "return" anything, maybe edit your question with some C++ code that shows what this dtor returning concept is?

Comment: I think the misunderstanding stems from you mistaking the `return` statement with the `ret` instruction. One returns a value in a given location (be that memory or register), the other returns the execution to a different point. What you've said therefore sounded like you imply destructors are called before the return value has been "acquired" which would be quite bad, but as I understand it, destructors are called AFTER the return value has been acquired and just before execution returns to the point of calling the returning function.

Comment: Post some C++ code that demos what you are talking about. Nothing is returned from a destructor.. post C++ code that has this issue and I'll show how it would look in "generated" code. If you extend out my example above to many classes it always works the same way.

Comment: Why do you keep on insisting that I imply a destructor returns a value? I never claimed such a thing. Are you not a native English speaker?

Comment: I am native - I don't understand your issue and I am asking for C++ code that you are having trouble with so that I can understand your problem. Are you talking about copying objects return value, returning an object from a function? Not very clear at all :)

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't understand? What I said is destructors cannot possibly run before the return statement has been executed, because the return statement might refer to data that destructors might destroy. The return statement of the function that is, not "return statement of destructors" which would not even make sense since destructors do not return by design.

Comment: No, if you had an object A that used data from B after B had been destructed then this is an error in C++, i.e dangling pointer. In C++ this would be solved by a move or a copy, I'll update my answer .

Comment: Please don't. You continue to not get my question, and your answer is entirely irrelevant to the question i asked. I'd actually downvote it if I had the rep, and suggest you simply remove it.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what you mean, returning an object from a std::vector<T>, how can you use the object after the vector is destructed? If not then your question is completely ambiguous and should be improved.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to illustrate a way to return complex object in C by mimicking move semantics to expand on Peter G. answer.

```
   struct T {
     char * data;
   };

   void swap(T * a, T * b) {
     swap(&a.data, &b.data);
   }

   void destruct(T & d) {
     free(d.data);
   }

   void foo(T * rv) {
      T x = {"Valueable data"};
      swap(rv, &x); //This is what return in C++ does
      destruct(&x); //This happens, when function  scope in C++ ends
   }

   void bar() {
     T holder = {0};
     foo(holder);
     destruct(&holder);
   }
```

Notice how allocation and deallocation of an object are always in the same scope.

Comment: I am really not that concerned with the moving of "movable" data, that's just good practice and efficient to do instead of copying. My question was strictly about the actual locals, not their underlying internals.

Comment: My point is, C function should not let calling code do cleanup. Once that condition is met, you are one step closer to RAII.

Comment: @user3735658 in that case it would be a copy ctor call instead of a swap call

Comment: @Basilevs I didn't exactly made that clear, and from my example it looks like `_redValue` is a local that also potentially needs destruction. But what I actually intended (but didn't really specify) is that `_retValue` is more like a POD, it contains the actual literal data and as such is exempt from being affected in any way by cleanup of locals. Provided this condition holds, can I expect the compiler to efficiently optimize to minimize and even eliminate redundant operations?

Comment: Which compiler? C++ optimizes everything. Of course swap would be called at the point when return value is known, making other caching or copies unnecessary. (Preallocated space would do the job of your _retValue).

Comment: Does it really matter? I think production grade compilers all implement the common basic optimizations to remove redundancies. E.g. I doubt any compiler will fail to optimize `int a; a = b + c; return a;` to be equivalent to `return b + c;`. But just if compilers really matter, let's say GCC.

Comment: Well, I miss your point. You wanted to known how C++ handles returns? I've tried to explain - there is a special "calling convention" (not exact term), that tries to optimize away extra copies and prevent resource leaks.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a value returned from a function must not refer to memory of local objects, that would be an error. So, to me it looks like you're possibly trying to solve a problem not even a C++ compiler has to solve.

If on the other you want simply want to return a value computed by one of the local objects, first assign the value computed by the object to a local variable, destruct the object and then return the pre-computed return value.

Comment: "n C++, a value returned from a function must not refer to memory of local objects" - that sounds like you imply it is an error to `int i = a - b; return i;` e.g. return statement refers to memory of local objects. But what I had in mind was say a dynamic array and returning an index of that array, obviously you cannot do that if the array destructor has already been executed and its memory is deleted.

Comment: you can return pointers so long as its still in scope, otherwise if its a value type then copy it

Comment: @user3735658 The return statement may refer to memory of local objects. The statement `return i` does just that. However the return value is a copy of i.

Comment: @paulm The function `int* a() { int b = 1; return &b; }` is not legal C or C++ in spite of b being in scope of the return statement.

Comment: Yeah I'm asking for example code that he is having trouble porting to C. In your example I would mean returning a pointer to &b if b is a class member before manually invoking the dtor, and only if b is a complex type.